# Django Unknown column in field list error

Tags: django

I am unsure why I am getting this error when I load order_processing.html

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'orchestration_ce_base.model' in 'field list'")
```

In models.py, I have just added the these:

model = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=ROUTER_MODELS)

region = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=REGION)

I assume they have not been created in the database. I have tried running makemigrations/migrate, but no changes are detected. When the html page is loaded it is throwing an error.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Order(models.Model):
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)#, null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Project_created_by', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_name

class Ce_Base(models.Model):

    ROUTER_MODELS = (
            ('CISCO2901', 'CISCO2901'),
            ('ISR4331', 'ISR4331'),
            ('CISCO1921', 'CISCO1921'),
            ('ISR4351', 'ISR4351'),
            ('ISR4451', 'ISR4451'),
            ('ISR4231', 'ISR4231'),
            ('ISR4431', 'ISR4431'),
            ('ISR4461', 'ISR4461'),
            )

    REGION = (
            ('1', '1'),
            ('2', '2'),
            ('3', '3'),
            ('4', '4'),
            ('5', '5'),
            ('6', '6'),
            ('7', '7'),
            )

    ce_hostname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    new = models.BooleanField()
    location = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=ROUTER_MODELS)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=REGION)

    order_reference = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Order
from .models import Ce_Base
from .forms import OrderForm
#from .tables import OrderTable
#from django_tables2 import RequestConfig

@login_required
def home(request):
    form = OrderForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm()
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        form.instance.created_by = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {
        'order': Order.objects.all(),
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'orchestration/order_create.html', context)

@login_required
def orderprocessing(request, pk_test):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk_test)
    ce_base = order.ce_base_set.all()

    context = {
        'order': order,
        'ce_base': ce_base

    }
    return render(request, 'orchestration/order_processing.html', context)
```

order_processing.html

```
{% extends "orchestration/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>CE Routers</h1>
  {% for each_ce_router in ce_base %}
    <p>CE Hostname: {{ each_ce_router.ce_hostname }}</p>
    <p>New: {{ each_ce_router.new }}</p>
    <p>Location: {{ each_ce_router.location }}</p>
    <p>Model: {{ each_ce_router.model }}</p>
    <p>Region: {{ each_ce_router.region }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by deleting everything in the database and starting again...A more in depth answer would be appreciated. I don't understand why this happened.